# NSPredicate to search through objects

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have to filter an array of objects by introducing a search keyword and filtering on the run. How am I supposed to do this?

```
//this is my Article class
@property  int intID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lang;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dateDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *dataPicture;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *link;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gallery;
@property int flag;
@property int subcat;
@property int cat;
@property int idpic;
```

I have to select article with contains text with introduced string

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{   
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"strName MATCHES '.*(%@).*'", searchText];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"strName MATCHES '.*%@.*' OR strTitle MATCHES '.*%@.*'", searchText, searchText]);
    
    articleSearchArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    articleSearchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[allArticleArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    for(Article *article in articleSearchArray)
    {
        
        NSLog(@"Article id is %i", article.intID);
    }
    [mytableView reloadData];
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"strName contains[c] '%@'", searchText];
```

This one will fetch all the objects in the array that their `strName` property contains `searchText` string, using a case-insensitive comparison (this is denoted with the `[c]`), which I think is what you're looking for.
After that, you just have to set the `NSArray` which acts as your datasource to the filtered one and do a `reloadData`.